# How to write an AutoHotkeys plugin to close all windows of specific class?

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

How can I close all the windows explorer windows?

```
winclose ahk_class CabinetWClass
```

I know how to close one window. How can I close all the windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use you code in a [loop](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Loop.htm) and every time [check](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfWinExist.htm) if there are any windows of that class left.
When there are none, exit the loop.

Comment: Thank you. This is works: loop 10 
winClose ahk_class CabinetWClass